# Display custom file in the content section when clicking a url in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I just started learning wordpress plugin and making a simple plugin. I got stuck in the process where I have a buy now button and I wanted if I click on that button it will display my custom form in the content area. I did the below code

```
 <a href="?hotel_booknow=2" class="btn btn-primary" id="create-user">Buy Now</a>
```

I want that it will call my below function that includes my custom file

```
    function jdbs_init(){

      if(isset($_GET['hotel_booknow']))
      {
       $content = include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/jdbs.php';
       //require  ('jdbs.php');
          return $content;
      }
     }

   add_action('init','jdbs_init');
```

If I clicked on that url it is including the jdbs.php file but it is appearing on the top of the page, above of header and display homepage. I want to display it on the main or content section.
 I tried to search it on google but no help.

jdbs.php:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Like in joomla we are making a controller and view in order to make pages so in wordpress how to make multiple pages or views for same plugin?

Comment: please add your jdbs.php file

Comment: @vrajesh, updated the question. please check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The init hook is called before the headers are sent, so it make sense that your included file is on top of your header.
See https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init

The right way to proceed is to tell Wordpress to use a different template file like this :

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'my_change_template' );

function my_change_template( $original_template ) {
  if (isset($_GET['hotel_booknow'])) {
    return 'jdbs.php';
  } else {
    return $original_template;
  }
}
```

That way it will use the jdbs.php to render the page. But then your need to put the header / footer part around your form (you can copy/paste them from page.php for example).

[Learn more about template files in Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Templates)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I was looking for that answer. I wanted to upvote your answer but it seems like that i don't have much points to vote.